# Book I read about a tin horse

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I have a very fuzzy recollection of a book I read in primary school in the early 1980's. It was about a few children and from what I remember a tin horse. However, I also seem to think there were balloons. I'm also sure it was based in Europe, France maybe.

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Were there any science fiction or fantasy elements you can remember?  Or was the tin horse somehow alive?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), especially to explain what (if anything) is scifi/fantasy about it.